# Velocity.js script not working in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I have used Velocity.js for my website , here is a sample [link](https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/scaledown.html) . Its not working on Safari browser on Desktop. What could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Velocity 1.2.2 in there - the latest public version is 1.5.1 which is now unsupported, and the latest beta version is 2.0.2 which has specific Safari fixes in it.